# Eclipse hangs my Win7 8gb RAM together with adb.exe

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adb

Eclipse together with adb.exe which i already suspected that suspended my Win7 8gb ram. why? + the fact that it doesn't run; I mean, it doesn't show the workspace. btw I am using eclipse with GAE and android, any conflict using both or is it ok nothing to worry?

Answer (score 0):

Try with a fresh installation of Android SDK. The system hangs when the adb.exe or any other file in the SDK gets corrupt.

Comment: It was a fresh installed and while I import too many files, that's how it goes.

Comment: I tried running eclipse alone (no adb.exe accompanied) deleted the .metadata on source project and the problem was still existing.. any clue??

Answer (score 0):

Increase you Xmx size for your eclipse, you can increase this in eclipse.ini(configuration settings file). It works

Answer (score 0):

Seems Eclipse is running out of memory. Open the `eclipse.ini` file which is located in your eclipse folder,  and increase the heap size.

You will get something as below

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.100.v20080501.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.0.100.v20080428-1330
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Now increase the `Xmx` to a higher value. May be something like 1024

Comment: I got 768Xmx. is there any visible graph or menu in eclipse which show this kind of configuration whether I cut or sort of?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not aware of such stuff. Increasing the memory size will keep the Eclipse run without crashing.

Comment: Hi Mayu, I already tried increasing the heap or stack with this configuration and no success after all.
<blockquote>
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms128m
-Xmx1280m</blockquote>